# Query and display result in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

[image]
I have the following code that query and display the result from database.

Database

id        title         desc
1         BUILD         The
2         BEAUTIFUL     Use

The piece of code in model folder

```
<?php
class Portfolio_model extends CI_Model {

        public function __construct()
        {
                $this->load->database();
        }

        public function get_webinfo()
        {
                $query = $this->db->select('title')->from('webinfo')->where('id', 1)->get();
                return $query->row_array();
        }
}
?>
```

The piece of code in controllers folder

```
<?php
    class Portfolio extends CI_Controller {

        public function view($portfolio = 'home')
        {
                if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'/views/portfolio/'.$portfolio.'.php'))
            {
                    // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
                    show_404();
            }

            $data['title'] = ucfirst($portfolio); // Capitalize the first letter

            $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('portfolio/'.$portfolio, $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
        }

        public function __construct()
        {
                parent::__construct();
                $this->load->model('portfolio_model');
                $this->load->helper('url_helper');
        }

        public function index()
        {
                $data['webinfo'] = $this->portfolio_model->get_webinfo();

                 $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
                $this->load->view('portfolio/index', $data);
                $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        }
    }
?>
```

The page that I want to display the data

```
<h2 class="intro-text text-center">
                        <strong><?php echo $webinfo['title']; ?></strong>
                    </h2>
```

However, I get the following error when I run the display page

```
A PHP ERROR WAS ENCOUNTERED

SEVERITY: NOTICE
MESSAGE: UNDEFINED VARIABLE: WEBINFO
```

May I know how should I go about editing the code to resolve the error?

Try 01
Controller

```
<?php
    class Portfolio extends CI_Controller {
        public function view($portfolio = 'home')
        {
                if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'/views/portfolio/'.$portfolio.'.php'))
            {
                    // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
                    show_404();
            }

            $data['title'] = ucfirst($portfolio); // Capitalize the first letter

            $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('portfolio/'.$portfolio, $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
        }

        public function __construct()
        {
                parent::__construct();
                $this->load->model('portfolio_model');
                $this->load->helper('url_helper');
        }

        public function index()
        {
                $data['webinfo'] = $this->portfolio_model->get_webinfo();

                print_r($data['webinfo']);
                /* $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
                $this->load->view('portfolio/index', $data);
                $this->load->view('templates/footer');*/
        }
    }
?>
```

Model

```
<?php
class Portfolio_model extends CI_Model {

        public function __construct()
        {
                $this->load->database();
        }

        public function get_webinfo()
        {
                $query = $this->db->query("SELECT title FROM webinfo WHERE id = 1");
                $result = $query->result_array();
                return $result;
        }
}
?>
```

view

```
<h2 class="intro-text text-center">
                        <strong><?php echo (!empty($webinfo[0]['title'])) ? $webinfo[0]['title'] : 'Empty Title' ;; ?></strong>
                    </h2>
```

Comment: could you `var_dump($data['web_info']);` in your index method for me please? and post the result here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**In Model**

```
public function get_webinfo()
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT title FROM webinfo WHERE id = 1");
    $result = $query->result_array();
    return $result;
}
```

**In View**

```
<h2 class="intro-text text-center">
    <strong><?php echo (!empty($webinfo['title'])) ? $webinfo['title'] : 'Empty Title' ;; ?></strong>
</h2>
```

***Note*: If I'm right sometimes this `$webinfo['title']` gives error and  its work fine with with `$webinfo[0]['title']`**

---

**And there is way to write controller.**

1. `__construct`
2. `index()`
3. then other all functions

**EDIT 01**

```
public function index()
{
    $data['webinfo'] = $this->portfolio_model->get_webinfo();

    print_r($data['webinfo']);
    /* $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('portfolio/index', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

controller:

```
    public function index()
        {
                $data['result'] = $this->portfolio_model->get_webinfo();

                 //$this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
                //$this->load->view('portfolio/index', $data);
               // $this->load->view('templates/footer');

                print_r($data);
        }
```

model

```
    public function get_webinfo()
{
   $this->db->select('*');
         $this->db->from('pwebinfo');
         $this->db->where('id',1);

$query = $this->db->get();

if($query->num_rows() ==''){
                return 'failure';       
        }else{
                $results = $query->result();        
                $result = $results[0];
                return $result; 
        }
}
```

view

```
 <h2 class="intro-text text-center">

 <strong> <?php echo $result[0]->title; ?> ?></strong>
 </h2>
```